# Access Denied for a user in a group that owns a folder

Tags: linux, permissions

[image]

[image]

Yet gitlabbackup user is unable to list the files in that folder.

```
[gitlabbackup@gitLAB-SRV gitlab]$ cd backups/
-bash: cd: backups/: Permission denied
```

Comment: the folder is missing execute permissions.

Comment: But I dont want that group to be able to execute anything...

Comment: Side note: This is text. It can be copied and pasted directly. No need for screenshots.

Comment: To be able to change into a directory you need execute permissions on that directory.

Comment: Is it possible at all to not be able to execute anything yet list the folder and reat it?

Comment: Type `man chmod` into your terminal. It will explain the difference between execute bit on a file versus a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no idea you needed "execute" permissions on a folder in order to access it...
Sounds counter-intuitive to say the least.

Thanks for the vote down though. Who ever may you be.